# Range of Beta in Kaiser Window

Tags: numpy, matlab, signal-processing, windowing

Why is the biggest value for Beta in the Kaiser Window function 709? I get errors when I use values of 710 or more (in Matlab and NumPy).
Seems like a stupid question but I'm still not able to find an answer...
Thanks in advance!

[image: Kaiser Window definition in NumPy]

This is the Kaiser window with a length of M=64 and Beta = 710.
[image: Kaiser Window M=64 and Beta=710]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?  (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  Your code snippet has several undefined variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large `x`, `i0(x)` is approximately `exp(x)`, and `exp(x)` overflows at x near 709.79.

If you are programming in Python and you don't mind the dependency on SciPy, you can use the function [`scipy.special.i0e`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.i0e.html) to implement the function in a way that avoids the overflow:

```
In [47]: from scipy.special import i0e

In [48]: def i0_ratio(x, y):
    ...:     return i0e(x)*np.exp(x - y)/i0e(y)
    ...:
```

Verify that the function returns the same value as `np.i0(x)/np.i0(y)`:

```
In [49]: np.i0(3)/np.i0(4)
Out[49]: 0.4318550956673735

In [50]: i0_ratio(3, 4)
Out[50]: 0.43185509566737346
```

An example where the naive implementation overflows, but `i0_ratio` does not:

```
In [51]: np.i0(650)/np.i0(720)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3359: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return exp(x) * _chbevl(32.0/x - 2.0, _i0B) / sqrt(x)
Out[51]: 0.0

In [52]: i0_ratio(650, 720)
Out[52]: 4.184118428217628e-31
```

In Matlab, to get the same scaled Bessel function as `i0e(x)`, you can use `besseli(0, x, 1)`.